# MySQL - Left joins without duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have an issue with some of the join statements I'm trying to use.  I have two tables that need to be joined, with both featuring all of their information.  They're as follows.

```
INSTITUTION
IName | ALocation_ID | IPicture

ADDRESS
ALocation_ID | AStreet | AZip | ...(other relevant fields)
```

I've been trying to use:

```
CREATE VIEW InstitutionView
AS SELECT * FROM INSTITUTION 
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS 
ON INSTITUTION.ALocation_ID=ADDRESS.ALocation_ID;
```

but the error I receive says something about duplicate columns.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is it so hard to put the exact error message rather than "something"?

Comment: I don't have access to the MySQL server I had to use at the moment, nor can i remember what the error was.

Comment: Incidentally, this naming policy will drive you nuts

Answer (score 1):

You will have to select the columns individually. Hopefully this helps you out a little.

```
CREATE VIEW InstitutionView
AS 
SELECT address.id,address.iname,address.alocation_id,ipicture,institution.astreet,institution.azip
FROM INSTITUTION 
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS 
ON INSTITUTION.ALocation_ID=ADDRESS.ALocation_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `ALocation_ID` column is present in both the tables.
Try creating the view explicitly naming the required columns.

```
CREATE VIEW InstitutionView
AS SELECT Iname,INSTITUTION.ALocation_ID,IPicture,AStreet,AZip ...
FROM INSTITUTION 
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS 
ON INSTITUTION.ALocation_ID=ADDRESS.ALocation_ID;
```

Comment: Would the statement be any different if ALocation_ID was a foreign key in the INSTITUTION table?  I'm thinking this might be the problem.  Also, since the values of ALocation_ID are identical for certain entries in each table (some institution might have an ID of 1, and its corresponding ADDRESS table entry would list it at 123 Some Street), I don't need the same value shown twice.

Comment: Since we join both tables with ALocation_ID same record will hold same ALocation_ID only. So no need to get the redundant data. Even though mysql threw error while creating the view, you will still get data from the view. Try select * from InstitutionView

Comment: the constraints dont matter. the name does

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, JOIN first creates an intermediate cross-product where the columns are referenced by a table name or alias dotted by a column name from that table; then ON and WHERE filter out rows that don't match to give a second intermediate result. If a column name appears only in one table then you can leave out the table & dot to refer to the column.

[MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: 13.2.9 SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

> You can refer to a column as col_name, tbl_name.col_name, or db_name.tbl_name.col_name. You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column reference unless the reference would be ambiguous. See Section 9.2.1, “Identifier Qualifiers”, for examples of ambiguity that require the more explicit column reference forms.

[MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: 9.2.1 Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

> Suppose that tables t1 and t2 each contain a column c, and you retrieve c in a SELECT statement that uses both t1 and t2. In this case, c is ambiguous because it is not unique among the tables used in the statement. You must qualify it with a table name as t1.c or t2.c to indicate which table you mean.

Hence:

```
CREATE VIEW InstitutionView
AS SELECT IName,I.ALocation_ID,IPicture,AStreet,AZip,...
FROM INSTITUTION I
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS A
ON I.ALocation_ID=A.ALocation_ID;
```

You might think that if a JOIN is ON or WHERE "=" then there would be no ambiguity. However:

In the case of INNER JOIN, if there were no implicit conversions then columns compared equal would have the same value; but otherwise different values can compare "=". So you can't use just the column name to identify one value.

Moreover for LEFT JOIN, unmatched rows in the left table are extended by NULLs and are added to give a third intermediate result; so in a row a non-NULL in a column in one table can appear with a NULL in the same column of the other table. So again you can't use just the column name to identify one value.

Moreover there doesn't even need to be a test of equality of two columns in a JOIN, or even mention both of or either of columns with a shared name. So the result can have two columns (one from each input table) sharing a name where there is no expectation of equality.